# Looping Through CSV Records in Playwright/Typescript Test Using Fixtures

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to loop through CSV records within a Playwright test using a fixture, but I'm unsure how to set up the test correctly. Here's what I have so far:

I have a Playwright fixture named test that retrieves records from a CSV file using the csv-parse library. This fixture is defined as follows:

```
import { test as baseTest } from "@playwright/test";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import { parse } from "csv-parse/sync";

const test = baseTest.extend<{
  records: string[]
}>({
  records: async ({}, use) => {
    const parsedRecords = parse(
      fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), process.env.app_qualys_filename)),
      { columns: true, skip_empty_lines: true }
    );
    await use(parsedRecords);
  },
});

export default test;
export const expect = test.expect;
```

I want to use this test fixture to create dynamic test cases that loop through each record and perform actions. Here's what I have in my test file:

```
import test, { expect } from "../src/app.qualys.utils/fixtures";
import logger from "../src/app.qualys.utils/logger";

let passCount = 0;
let failCount = 0;

for (const record of records) {
  test(`Qualys dashboard: ${record.dashboard_name}`, async ({page}
    , testInfo) => {
    // Need help with how to structure the test
  });
}
```

I'm unsure how to structure the test to properly use the records from the fixture and loop through each record to perform actions within the test. Can you please provide guidance on how to achieve this?

I've tried different approaches, but I'm struggling to figure out how to access the records array from the fixture within each individual test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use **test.step** inside of a test if you want to use a fixture. **records** in this case is a test context, not fixture so you can't loop it outside of **test()**

```js
import test from "./fixtures";

test(`Quality dashboard:`, async ({ records }) => {
  for (const record of records) {
    await test.step(`Record ${record}`, async () => {
      console.log(record);
    });
  }
});
```

or do it without fixture

```js
import { test } from "@playwright/test";
import * as fs from "fs";
import { parse } from "csv-parse/sync";

const records = parse(fs.readFileSync("input.csv"), {
  columns: true,
  skip_empty_lines: true,
});

for (const record of records) {
  test(record, async ({}) => {
    console.log(record);
  });
}
```

Comment: Super bro, It works well. Thank you very much for your time and reply.